AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'lazy_load'
def load_docs(folder_path):

data_list = []
for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.pdf")):
    loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path)
    docs = loader.load()
    
    loader_all = MergedDataLoader(docs) #
    docs_all = loader_all.load() #
    print(len(docs_all)) # here I'm expecting len of all pdf pages for ex. (pdf-1 has 1 pg, pdf-2 has 2 pg then total len should be 3)
    # data = docs[0].page_content
    # data_list.append((file_path, data))


return data_list

Above code is working for loading each PDF and then storing its content in a data_list but I wanted to load all the PDF files in a single docs such that I can pass it to further processing. I tried using MergedDataLoader but getting above error.
Any suggestions or solutions?

MergedDataLoader is supposed to receive a list of loaders, not a list of documents. You should give it the list of all the loaders of your pdf files (ie, do not run .load() before giving it to the MergedDataLoader, and put your MergedDataLoader outside of your for loop):
def load_docs(folder_path):

    loaders = [
        PyPDFLoader(file_path)
        for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.pdf"))
    ]
        
    loader_all = MergedDataLoader(loaders)
    docs_all = loader_all.load()

    return docs_all

But then, it is quite similar to what PyPDFDirectoryLoader would do

def load_docs(folder_path):
    all_docs = []  # Initialize an empty list to hold all pages of all PDFs
    
    for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.pdf")):
        loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path)
        docs = loader.load()  # Load the PDF pages
        
        all_docs.extend(docs)  # Add all pages of this PDF to the list
    
    print(len(all_docs))  # Total number of pages across all PDFs
    
    return all_docs  # Return the combined list of all pages

To combine all the PDF files' pages into a single docs object for further processing, you don't need a separate MergedDataLoader. Instead, you can manually aggregate the loaded pages from each PDF into a single list.
Still if you want to use it. Here is the updated code.
def load_docs(folder_path):
    # Load all PDFs in the folder
    loaders = [PyPDFLoader(file_path) for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.pdf"))]
    
    # Merge loaded PDFs
    loader_all = MergedDataLoader(loaders)
    all_docs = loader_all.load()

    print(len(all_docs))
    return all_docs

